# memcached server return null value when retrive java objects value from memcached server

Tags: java, caching, memcached

I did memcached implementation and identified objects moved to memcache, but I have some problems with get it from memcached. So in my application, (it is a reservation system) I can search  and get the Result list ,but when I select hotel,or Flight, or Activity it says memdown, memcach error. I listed some codes and methods I used and pls help me to solve this problem.I really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

My app is Struts mvc based. and I used below 3 methods in action files, and some jsp files.
I did memcaching identified objects , using below methods.

```
private RezSession rezSession   = null;
    //Moving identified objects to memcached server
private void setToCache(String attributeName, Object value,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    rezSession = new RezSession();
    rezSession.setAttribute(attributeName, value, request);
}

private Object getFromCache(String attributeName, HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception {
    rezSession = new RezSession();
    return (Object) rezSession.getAttribute(attributeName,request);
}

private void removeFromCache(String attributeName, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
    rezSession = new RezSession();
    rezSession.removeAttribute(attributeName,request);
}
```

Above methods redirect to Rezsession methods listed below.
AbstractSessionObject is a interface , two of java classes implements it.

1. CacheSessionImplementer.java
2. HttpSessionImplementer.java

RezSession.java methods:-

```
public  void setAttribute(String key,Object value, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    try {
        //AbstractSessionObject abstractSessionObject = RezSessionFactory.getInstance().getAbstractSessionObject();
        if("ResPkgSearchForm".equals(key))
            logger.debug(">>> Setting +:- "+key + " Class:"+(value==null?null:value.getClass()));
        AbstractSessionObject abstractSessionObject = RezSessionFactory.getInstance().getSessionSpacificInstance(session);
        abstractSessionObject.setAttribute(request,key,value,null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.fatal("error from new setAttribute",e);
    }
}

public  Object getAttribute(String key, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    try {   
        //AbstractSessionObject abstractSessionObject = RezSessionFactory.getInstance().getAbstractSessionObject();
        AbstractSessionObject abstractSessionObject = RezSessionFactory.getInstance().getSessionSpacificInstance(session);
        Object value = abstractSessionObject.getAttribute(request,key,null);
        if("ResPkgSearchForm".equals(key))
            logger.debug(">>> Getting +:- "+key + " Class:"+(value==null?null:value.getClass()));
        return value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        request.setAttribute("MEMDOWN", "Y");
        logger.fatal("error from new getAttribute",e);
    }
    return null;
}

public  void removeAttribute(String key, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    try {

        AbstractSessionObject abstractSessionObject = RezSessionFactory.getInstance().getSessionSpacificInstance(session);
        abstractSessionObject.removeAttribute(request,key,null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug("error from new removeAttribute",e);
    }
}
```

1. CacheSessionImplementer.java --Memcache implementer of AbstractSessionObject :::: this method Used for get from Memcached. 
   Below code "public Object getAttribute(), CacheSessionImplementer.java" called from "public  Object getAttribute(), RezSesion.java."

   ```
   public Object getAttribute(HttpServletRequest request,String key,Object additionalParam) throws Exception{

   SessionValueContainer sessionValueContainer = null;
   CacheResults cacheResults = null;
   String seqNo = "";
   if (null != request.getParameter("seqNo") 
           && !request.getParameter("seqNo").equals("") 
               && !request.getParameter("seqNo").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
       seqNo = request.getParameter("seqNo");
   } else if (null != request.getAttribute("seqNo")){
       seqNo = request.getAttribute("seqNo").toString();
   }

   String requestString = getRequestString(request.getSession().getId(),seqNo);

   Object value = getCachedValue(key,requestString);

   return value;
   }
   ```

   Here EngineFactory is selecting whihc caching engine should be select.

   ```
   private Object getCachedValue(String key, String requestString)
       throws Exception, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
       ClassNotFoundException {
   Object value = get(key, requestString);
   if (value != null && value instanceof String) {
       String new_mem_key = (String) value;
       // logger.debug("key ~>"+key+" --new_mem_key ~>"+new_mem_key);
       if ("MEM".equals(((String) value).split("#")[0])) {
           logger.debug("value before------------->" + value);// --getting
                                                               // values
                                                               // correctly---1
           value = factory.getCacheEngine(memCacheKey).getObject(
                   new_mem_key);// value is ok and redirect to
                                   // EngineFactory---2
           logger.debug("value After------------->" + value);// --getting
                                                               // null for
                                                               // value---3
           if (value == null) {
               logger.debug("MEMCACH-ERROR");
               throw new NullPointerException("MEMDOWN");
           }
       }
   }
   return value;
   }
   ```

In my case , when I am selecting a hotel or flight or activity, in getCachedValue() method(Above one)

```
    logger.debug("value before------------->"+value);//-----------------------------getting values correctly---1
value = factory.getCacheEngine(memCacheKey).getObject(new_mem_key);//value is ok and redirect to EngineFactory---2
logger.debug("value After------------->"+value);//-------------------------------getting null for value---3
```

So I can't get values from Cache. I 
In my app, Moving fromsession to memcached server is fine but, getFromCache is stuck. So I ecpecting good solutions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those classes implement `java.io.Serializable`? You can keep only Serialized Objects in MemCache, as it stores the objects in Secondary Memory.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, I implemented java.io.Serializable in CacheSessionImplementer,RezSession,AbstractSessionObject and EngineFactory, and some main action classes. do I need to implement to all java classes which relted to memcache.

Comment: Hi Nazoordeen. Are objects of these classes that you are storing is Memcached? Or are they different? I could see these classes are used to retrieve the data from Cache/Session.

Comment: Hi Raghavendra, I am storing this at memcached, that process is working fine. but when I'm getting from memcached, then I am getting memdown error, and null value return. I'm retriving data from mecache using codes in CacheSessionImplementer.java. I updated above Question with the code block. once again thank you.